# JMH Benchmark first approach

Tags: java, testing, benchmarking, jmh

I am approaching for the first time the benchmark tests for my thesis work and I'm studying JMH.
I'm using the https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-rest code to do some tests.
After initializing JMH I obtained the class:

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;

public class MyBenchmark {

    @Benchmark
    public void testMethod() {
        // This is a demo/sample template for building your JMH benchmarks. Edit as needed.
        // Put your benchmark code here.

    }

}
```

If I run `mvn clean package` it generates the `target/spring-petclinic-rest-2.6.2-perf-tests.jar` file and if I do `java -jar target/spring-petclinic-rest-2.6.2-perf-tests.jar` I obtain some results.

My question is, with this simple *MyBenchmark* class with the empty *testMethod* method, what is this benchmark test applied to? What code did he test?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it tested nothing particular as the benchmarking method it empty. The numbers you are seeing are the the costs of the method invocation.